# Does Angularjs support with in template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

If I have $scope.data={"user" {"firstname":test"}}, I am hoping to have template like

{% with data %}
 user name is {{ user.firstname }}

or

{% with data.user %}
 user name is {{ firstname }}

somthing like that, but I could not find it. I think it is not ideal to always use full path like {{ data.user.firstname }}

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know AngularJS doesn't support with, that's python. I see no problems in accessing:

```
{{ data.user.firstname }}
```

in your templates. If you don't like that "data." why don't you just assign:

```
let data={ user: { firstname: "test"} };   
$scope.user = data.user;
```

and then you will be able to use in your templates:

```
{{ user.firstname }}
```

Another thing you can use is directive - set up your own custom directive and pass values you want through a binding that will give you property on $scope you want. So in HTML you could do something like this:

```
<some-directive user="data.user" />
```

and then in directive (given that you have module stored in variable `app`):

```
app.directive('someDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      user: '='
    },
    template: 'Name: {{user.firstname}}'
  };
});
```

More about directives: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive